# Pushnotification changes for App Store

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I am new in iPhone.

I have implemented push notification in  my iPhone app. It is working fine for development and AdHoc distribution .

I am archiving my app using My "Apple AdHoc  Push notification Provision Profile" and in build setting for code signing identity i have set Apple development certificate as build for "Debug" and "Release".

Now i want to go for live which necessary changes i have to do on my web server and also in my app ?

Thank You in advance.

Comment: Nothing, since you have tested using Adhoc and will be using the same APPID to submit, it should be same, but YES you just need to check your api, that must be using `gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com`. Change that to `gateway.push.apple.com`.

Comment: Are you talking about Bundle identifier ?

Comment: NO, if you are going to use the same Bundle Identifier as used in Adhoc, you just need to change the push notification gateway.. But if you are changing, then you need to create pem file again.